# How to apply brick texture to rectangular (yet irregular) object?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I have a brick texture which I have made here:

[image]

And I would like to apply it to the red faces of this object:

[image]

However, this is the outcome of my attempt:
[image]

I would like to keep the bricks on that rectangular object the same as on the cube (first picture).

What approach should I take to handling this issue?

I have attached the blender file if you'd like to play around with it:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried properly UV unwrapping the structure? And are there supposed to be multiple textures (like the red one) on the structure?

Comment: Not on that particular object, no. I also intend to put a separate object on the countertops (like a marble tabletop) so I only need to show the sides. I also haven't UV unwrapped this object at all, I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing select all the faces and assign the good material:

[image]

As you see in the *Shader Editor*, you're using the *Texture Coordinate* UV output, but as you see in the *UV Editor* the UVs of your object are not correctly scaled and rotated:

[image]

So you need to unwrap again (keep these faces selected and press <kbd>U</kbd>), select the UVs in the *UV Editor*, rotate and scale like that for example:

[image]